# Create a ROOT AWS Role that can do anything

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, amazon-iam

I've been struggling recently with AWS Roles.
I'm an indie-hacker so I need to move and iterate quickly with my ideas. I found myself dealing with a lot of AWS permissions roles.
I understand that this roles are critical and you need to only grant permissions to what the service/app actually needs, but I need to find a way to create a "ROOT" AWS role that has ability to DO ANYTHING.

Of course if my app matures I'll improve the security and create the right roles and policies but for now that's what I need to move quick.

Is there a way to achieve this?

This is an example I'm currently dealing with..

```
(base) ╭─figo@FIGO-Macbook-Pro ~/projects/git_kickstartgit/app ‹feature/improve-docker-server-health› 
╰─$ eb deploy
Creating application version archive "app-230906_114450703083".
Uploading docker_app/app-230906_114450703083.zip to S3. This may take a while.
Upload Complete.
2023-09-06 10:44:51    INFO    Environment update is starting.      
2023-09-06 10:44:54    ERROR   Failed to check health. Verify the permissions on the environment's service role and try again later. Permissions changes take up to two hours to propagate.
2023-09-06 10:44:54    ERROR   Failed to deploy application.        
                                                                      
ERROR: ServiceError - Failed to deploy application.
```

Comment: How are you getting limited permissions right now?

Answer (score 0):

AWS provides the `AdministratorAccess` managed policy, which can be attached to any role. This policy grants full access to all services; there are only a few things (such as changing account ownership) that it cannot do.

After you're done with initial development, you can then replace this policy with a least-privilege policy that's appropriate to your application.

#### Side comment: why use roles, and in particular why *not* to use the account's root user.

In general, roles are the best way to grant permissions to your applications for the following reasons:

- The ability to assume a role is built-in to all of the AWS compute resources.
- The trust policy of a role can limit who/what has access to that role (eg, it can be assumed by EC2 but not an actual user).
- The permissions granted by a role have limited duration, limiting "blast radius" if they're leaked.

The main reason to *not* use the root user is that your applications will need to use access keys, which means those access keys will be stored somewhere. If they're accidentally stored in a public location, or accessible via some bug in your application, then you can expect your account to be taken away from you.

Maybe it will just be used for crypto-mining, and you can spend weeks debating your bill with AWS. If you have an actual business, maybe it puts you out of business. Google for examples.